# How to save data in a DB field that is not listed as part of a DJango CreateView

Tags: django, view

I have the following `CreateView` where I am trying to **Mstrstorehead-contactemail** with the email address of the person who has logged in.

The problem is that **contactemail** is not listed as one of the fields to be displayed on the `CreateView` form (which is `MstrstoreheadCreate`)

How can I get this field assigned?

**views.py**

```
class MstrstoreheadCreate(CreateView):
    model = Mstrstorehead
    fields = ['companyname',
              'taxeinno', 'companyname', 'abanumber', 'businesstypeid', 'ourmission', 'contactsalutationid',
              'contactfirstname', 'contactlastname', 'contactofficephoneno', 'contactcellphoneno' ]
    template_name_suffix = '_mstr_create_form'

    def form_valid(self, form):

        mhead = form.save(commit=False)

        mhead.contactemail = self.request.user.email  << contactemail is part of the model but NOT part of the fields used in CreateView

        return super(MstrstoreheadCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Go to your view (the one you handle the form) and add that over there... something like this:

```
def MyView(request):
    mhead = MstrstoreheadCreate()
    if request.method == "POST":
        mhead = MstrstoreheadCreate(request.POST)
        if mhead.is_valid():
           mhead.contactemail = self.request.user.email 
           mhead.save()
```